# Java Web application getting Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1776 for HADR configured on DB2

Tags: servlets, db2, jndi

I have developed a web application where in i've configured two `<Resource>` with proper parameters in server.xml of Apache tomcat server, Using JNDI connection pool. Among two resource tags in server.xml, first  tag is having details of primary server and another  tag contains the details of standby server. My idea is if i dont get connection from primary for certain time, I'll switch the datasource to standby and run the query from servlet. But when I ran the code, It gave me the error `Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1776, SQLSTATE=     , SQLERRMC=1, DRIVER=3.57.82)`

I googled lot but cant find any concrete answer about this, but one thing was common in all i.e. HADR(Hisgh Availability Disaster Recovery) configuration of DB2 server.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you cannot connect to the standby database unless it assumes the primary role after the take-over.

The correct way of setting up a DB2 HADR cluster is to configure a virtual IP address in your cluster management software that gets assigned to the new primary database after the take-over; while the change remains completely transparent for client applications.

You'll need to talk to your DBAs to learn how to configure the application.

Comment: But does from application's point of view, we've any programming logic to sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

In a HADR configuration, each time the database flips from primary to standby and the standby to primary, the Server will send ClientReroute Exception to each client connected to DB2 server, So I've caught it programtically and and tried the transaction again and it succeeded.